# Vagrant / Chef-solo not working after running recipe rvm::vagrant

Tags: rvm, chef-infra

After adding recipe rvm::vagrant and running vagrant provision I got:

```
/usr/local/bin/chef-solo: line 23: /opt/vagrant_ruby/bin/chef-solo: No such file 
or directory
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

This issue should have been fixed:
https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rvm/issues/121

Even though I add the line:

```
'rvm' => {
    'vagrant' => {
      'system_chef_solo' => '/opt/vagrant_ruby/bin/chef-solo'
    }
  }
```

I am still getting the error. How can I recover from it?

Comment: Did you try deleting and then creating the box again?

Comment: I ended up switching to rbenv for this experiment.

Answer (score 6):

You have to make sure that '/opt/vagrant_ruby/bin/chef-solo' is actual path of `chef-solo`.  In my case it was `/usr/bin/chef-solo`. And this is part of my `Vagrantfile` that fixed it:

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  chef.json.merge! rvm: {vagrant: {system_chef_solo: '/usr/bin/chef-solo'}}
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Will take me some time to see if my question is still relevant and verify the answer.

Comment: on my node, chef-solo is installed at /usr/local/bin/chef-solo, and setting it's path as you're showing in the Vagrantfile isn't working, either. Darn, it was working great until I added the vagrant recipe.

Comment: Can I just point out that brackets are needed around the merge conditions {rvm: {...}

Comment: You are right @simonmorley answer had a syntax error, I just updated it by removing external pair of curly brackets, that is another way.

Answer (score 0):

This has been frustrating as answers are very time dependent. I have had this issue though and fixed it today by adding to my Vagrantfile. I had to `vagrant destroy` and `vagrant up` again so hopefully this doesn't break next time I `vagrant provision` but I have checked in the box and it looks like the path to chef-solo is correct. Found this answer out on Github at [here](https://github.com/chef/vagrant-omnibus/issues/70)

```
chef.json = {
  rvm: {
        vagrant: {
          system_chef_solo: '/opt/chef/bin/chef-solo'
        },
        user_installs: [
            {
                user: 'vagrant',
                default_ruby: '2.2.1',
                rubies: ['2.2.1'],
                global: '2.2.1'
            }
        ]
    },
... rest of Vagrantfile
```